# vim not allowing backspace

Tags: vim

File `foo` has text:

```
This| is a line.
```

If I place the cursor at the `|`, hop into `insert` mode, and press <kbd>backspace</kbd>, nothing happens. If I type something, I can delete the things I've typed, but only back to where the insertion began. For example, if I place the cursor at the end of the line, and type `word`, I can delete `word` but can't delete the `.` or anything to the left of it.

This is rather annoying. What `vim` setting does this?

Comment: Some say you fix that by using the vim setting in emacs.

Comment: You can always place cursor over the character and push d then l. That will delete 1 character going right.

Comment: @scrappedcola, you could also save a keystroke by simply typing `x`. But if you want to *change* the character, you can use `r<newchar>`, or, to enter insert mode, `cl`, which can come in pretty handy. (in fact, `c<any motion>` works)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

#### Explanation

The 'backspace' setting controls this behavior.

From the help page:

```
Influences the working of <BS>, <Del>, CTRL-W and CTRL-U in Insert
mode.  This is a list of items, separated by commas.  Each item allows
a way to backspace over something:

value   effect
indent  allow backspacing over autoindent
eol     allow backspacing over line breaks (join lines)
start   allow backspacing over the start of insert; CTRL-W and CTRL-U
            stop once at the start of insert.
```

---

#### Changing backspace behavior

Try adding the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start " backspace over everything in insert mode
```

A short-hand version of the same command:

```
set backspace=2
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `vim`:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

If you're using `vi`:

```
vi ~/.exrc
```

Then add this line to the top of the file:

```
set nocompatible
```

Save the file and that should fix it

Comment: The existence of a `vimrc` is enough to trigger `nocompatible`, see `:help 'compatible'`. Furthermore, your answer implicitly relies on Vim's default `cpoptions`. Specifically the absence of the `v` flag, see `:help cpo-v`. Unless you have a very good reason for doing so, don't use `~/.exrc`. This is generally bad advice.